# Manage permissions to run azure devops pipelines and permissions to change variable groups pragmatically

Tags: rest, security, azure-devops

I am reading through this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops, I can't see a clear answer on how one can manage permissions to run pipelines and permissions to edit variable groups through the Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

For security management with REST APIs you can refer to [Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for details. Some of the REST APIs are not documented, however we can track them by develop tools (the simplest way is pressing F12 in your browser).

In your scenario seems you are trying to manage the permission of the pipelines in a specific project. If so, we can navigate to the **Pipeline** node -> **Manage security** -> Select the specific group/user to set the permission accordingly, (Just track the APIs when do the actions).

To run the pipelines, we at least need the `View build pipeline` , `View builds`, `Queue builds` permissions. You can also set other permissions as needed.

For example, just **Deny** the `Queue builds` permission for the **Contributors** group:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{Project}/_api/_security/ManagePermissions?api-version=5.1

Sample Request Body:
{"updatePackage":"{\"IsRemovingIdentity\":false,\"TeamFoundationId\":\"24cb2a78-4d79-49d6-b96c-bf0ac65d7032\",\"DescriptorIdentityType\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity\",\"DescriptorIdentifier\":\"S-1-9-1551374245-3809964236-1275365961-2582801090-4223875273-1-492339072-1927234371-3142690236-612141869\",\"PermissionSetId\":\"33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9\",\"PermissionSetToken\":\"cc7017e3-044c-498a-99f2-6ac2fbc338c9\",\"RefreshIdentities\":false,\"Updates\":[{\"PermissionId\":2,\"PermissionBit\":128,\"NamespaceId\":\"33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9\",\"Token\":\"cc7017e3-044c-498a-99f2-6ac2fbc338c9\"}],\"TokenDisplayName\":null}"}
```

Do the same things to track the APIs to manage the variable groups.

In addition, you can also use the Azure CLI to manage the permissions, refer to [az devops security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security?view=azure-cli-latest) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Indeed I already started to use  Ado REST API to manage permissions, as you suggested, the  huge problem lies here - " Some of the REST APIs are not documented,", I'd some MANY. Still a lot of gaps making it's harder to use. I finally coped with that in empirical way , but the problem remains.

Comment: @AlexeyMelezhik Yeah, a little complicated with the REST APIs to manage the permissions, we need to track the namespaceID,Bit, token etc, it has different attributes for each permission item. Compare to the REST API, the Azure CLI is more straightforward - [az devops security permission update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-permission-update). Whatever, we can track them if we want to use the REST APIs to manage the permissions. BTW, if the reply helps, you could freely accept it as an answer.

Comment: Hi Andy. Thank for that. Az cli is not ideal for automation at least for my environment. I meant RestAPI.  "if the reply helps, you could freely accept it as an answer. "  It's more or less corresponds my initial knowledge _before_ I post the question.

Comment: OK, however currently that's the only way to use REST API to manage the permissions, just track them.